# How to use MapStruct with only primitive properties as sources?

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have the follow object:

```
@Value
public class CompanyDto {
    int id;
    int accountId;
}
```

And i try to use `MapStruct` *(version `1.5.2.Final`)* for mapping two primitive properties to new `CompanyDto` object:

```
@Mapper
public interface CompanyMapper {

    CompanyDto mapToDto(int id, int accountId);
}
```

And i get compiling error:

> error: illegal start of expression
>
> ```
>     if (  ) {
>           ^
> ```

So i see that `MapStruct` tries to check something for `null` value but there are not any objects which can be checked for `null` and it generates empty `if` condition which is cause of the compiling error.

Is this bug or i do something wrong?

Comment: Since you only use two parameters to create a new Object could you not use a vanilla java consturctor or a builder? To me that would seem like the simplest solution.

Comment: @GJohannes i agree with you, but i wonder why i don't have the possibility of doing this by means of mapstruct

Comment: you should define @Mapping(source,target) annotation in your mapstruct

Comment: @debugmode no, u should'nt define Mapping if u have not to make specific handling for mapping properties. And it does not make any difference

Comment: why don't you pass CompanyEntity as parameter?

Comment: @PaulMarcelinBejan because it does'not make any sense so i don't have entity